# Making a single line bold in a JTextPane without using HTML

Tags: java, html, swing, jtextarea

I'm trying to bold a single line in my JTextPane, but nothing I do is working.
I've tried writing the line with a new, bolded font, but it didn't help.

```
 Font font = new Font("Consolas", Font.BOLD, 11);
            textPane.setFont(font);
            textPane.setText(textPane.getText() + "\n" + getTimeStamp() + sender + ": " + message);
            textPane.setFont(defaultFont);
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to do this, is to get the StyledDocument from the JTextPane, and to use the setCharacterAttributes() method.

The setCharacterAttributes method on the StyledDocument object allows you to set for a specific character range, a set of attributes, which can include BOLD.

See the [Javadoc for more info](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/text/StyledDocument.html#setCharacterAttributes%28int,%20int,%20javax.swing.text.AttributeSet,%20boolean%29)

Some sample code could be

```
// set chars 4 to 10 to Bold
SimpleAttributeSet sas = new SimpleAttributeSet(); 
StyleConstants.setBold(sas, true);
textPane.getStyledDocument().setCharacterAttributes(4, 6, sas, false);
```

Comment: can you give me an example? That would be really great.

Comment: there is one there for you now.

Comment: why asking for code, here http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html +1

Comment: Happy to help. Swing can be a minefield some times!

Comment: Another problem: The first time I run the method, it works. The buttom line gets bolded. But the next time I run the method, it adds another line of text but everything returns to normal (non-bolded).

Answer (score 2):

Something to watch out for is to ensure that the font family you use actually has a bold font on your system. I started out using Monaco (on OSX) which only includes a regular font. Nothing worked until I switched to Menlo, which had a Menlo Bold entry.

Here is some code based on Oracle's example.

```
StyledDocument document = textPane.getStyledDocument ();
Style defaultStyle =
      StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext ().getStyle (StyleContext.DEFAULT_STYLE);
Style regular = document.addStyle ("regular", defaultStyle);

StyleConstants.setBackground (regular, backgroundColor);
StyleConstants.setFontFamily (regular, "Menlo");
StyleConstants.setFontSize (regular, 14);

blackStyle = document.addStyle ("BlackStyle", regular);
StyleConstants.setForeground (blackStyle, Color.black);

redStyle = document.addStyle ("RedStyle", regular);
StyleConstants.setForeground (redStyle, Color.red);
StyleConstants.setBold (redStyle, true);
```